# Rails - TypeError: can't cast Array to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to seed data into my database using `rake db:seed`. I get the following error `TypeError: can't cast Array to string`

My code

```
db/seeds.rb
locations_list = [
  ["Melbourne"],
  ["Sydney"],
  ["Canberra"],
  ["Newcastle"]
]

locations_list.each do |location|
  Location.create(city: location)
end

universities = [
  ["M University"],
  ["T University of M"],
  ["R Institute of M"],
  ["S University of T"],
  ["L University"],
  ["D University"],
  ["V University"]
]

universities.each do |university|
  University.create(name: university)
end
```

Looking through it, the syntax seems to be inorder. Can't seem to find why it's bringing up that error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building an array of arrays, so `location` or `university` in the iterations are arrays of their own.

You don't need the extra [] around each one of the strings.

```
universities = [
  "M University",
  "T University of M",
  "R Institute of M",
  "S University of T",
  "L University",
  "D University",
  "V University"
]
```

Comment: I've just tried that and it works, thanks for the help